# PHP regex find word (even with double letters) then replace it

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace, str-replace

I'm using PHP to create a string filter. I need to replace some words by other words so I'm using the str_replace() function like this :

```
$phrase  = "You should eat fruits, vegetables, and fiber every day.";
$healthy = array("fruits", "vegetables", "fiber");
$yummy   = array("pizza", "beer", "ice cream");
$newphrase = str_replace($healthy, $yummy, $phrase);
// echo -> "You should eat pizza, beer, and ice cream every day.";
```

So far so good but I need to replace words even if they contains several letters like this:

```
$phrase  = "You should eat fruuits, vegetaaables, and fiiibeeer every day.";
```

I found this example to remove double letters in a string:

```
$string = preg_replace('/(\w)\1+/', '$1', $phrase);
```

But if I apply this example to my string, all words with double letters will be changed... For example "Google" will become "Gogle" and I don't want that.

Any ideas ? Thanks!

Comment: I'm curious about the reason to include these specific misspellings

Comment: You could put an `*` after each letter that would allow for multiples of that letter. Although there are numerous spelling errors that could be present.

Comment: @BenMansley: I'm trying to remove some rude words from a list titles. I'd like to replace words like "f*ck" or "s*ck" by "luck" or "duck". The problem is that lot of rude words are written like this "f****ck" or "sss*****ck"... You see?

Comment: I think the way the question is asked makes it too broad. Could you narrow down a bit? Since in your example, you merged vowels other than`o`, use `'/([aueiy])\1+/i'`, as `oo` is a valid and frequent vowel combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something like this

```
$phrase  = "You should eat suck, sck, and suuucky every day.";
$healthy = 's+u*c+k+';
$yummy = 'luck';
$newphrase = preg_replace('/' . $healthy . '/', $yummy, $phrase);
echo $newphrase;
```

Output:

```
You should eat luck, luck, and lucky every day.
```

The `+` is quantifier meaning one or more of the previous character. The `*` is a zero or more quantifier meaning the character doesn't have to be present but if it is any number of that character can be present.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/sN5sZ6/1

Also with `ass` word boundaries should be used because you don't want to be replacing `class` etc. https://regex101.com/r/oM4wY1/2 Kinda becomes a winding road though..

Answer (score 0):

If you want specific words then you can use multiple patterns in the `preg_replace`.

For your example you can use multiple patterns like this:

```
$phrase  = "You should eat fruits, vegetables, and fiber every day.";
$patterns = array("/fru+its/", "/vegeta+bles/", "/fi+be+r/");
$yummy   = array("pizza", "beer", "ice cream");
$newphrase = preg_replace($patterns, $yummy, $phrase);
```

In case you want to detect only `fruits`, `vegetables` and `fiber`, then you could use:

```
$patterns = array("f+r+u+i+t+s+", "v+e+g+e+t+a+b+l+e+s+", "f+i+b+e+r+");
```

**[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jX3rD9/1)**

**[IdeOne code example](https://ideone.com/2Wmv9u)**

Comment: You'll need delimiters too.

Answer (score 0):

Working example

```
$word =array('fiber', 'milk', 'nuts'); // words to scan for
$phrase = "You should eat fibeeer, nuuuuts, and milkkk every day."; //phrase
$filter = array(); // array of dynamicly generated filters

foreach($word as $name){ // loop for filter generating
    $temp = str_split($name);
    $temp = implode('{1,}', $temp). '{1,}';
    $filter[$name] = $temp;
}


$phraseTable = explode(' ', $phrase); // getting phrase into an array

foreach($phraseTable as &$data){ // scanning phrase
    foreach($filter as $name => $value){
         if(  preg_match( '/'.$value.'[,.]?/', $data)){
             $data = $name;
    }  
    } 
}       

$phraseScanned = implode(' ', $phraseTable); // imploding formatted phrase
echo $phraseScanned;  // echo result
```